# python split string using alphabet to get only numerical values

Tags: python, pandas

Using python 3.8

Given str = `A11B11C32D34,....`

I want to split it into [11, 11, 32, 34 ...]. Meaning split using alphabets. How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with pandas it's `df['strcol'].str.extractall('(\d+)')`.

Comment: Are you using Pandas or just regular Python?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using python but would like to know for pandas as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with

```
s= 'A11B11C32D34'
s
Out[388]: 'A11B11C32D34'
import re
re.findall(r'\d+', s)
Out[390]: ['11', '11', '32', '34']
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you! I will accept it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I might also suggest using a regex split approach here:

```py
inp = "A11B11C32D34"
nums = [x for x in re.split(r'\D+', inp) if x]
print(nums)  # ['11', '11', '32', '34']
```

The idea here is to split the string on any one or more collection of non digit characters.  I also use a list comprehension to remove any leading/trailing empty entries in the output from `re.split` which might arise due to the string starting/ending with a non digit character.